# M2 Varnish + Nginx (SSL not caching)

Tags: magento2, ssl, nginx, varnish

After configuring Magento 2 under SSL on every page successfully ([HTTPS everywhere - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116564/https-everywhere-magento-2/116577#116577)) I have found a problem on SSL since why I open this question.

If I enable SSL with NGINX as a Proxy I loose cache on the whole website. I suspect the problem is in the VCL configuration file but I cannot find the error.

My setup:

1. Server 01 --> Varnish + Nginx --> 192.168.1.22
   Varnish is configured to listen on port 80
2. Server 02 --> Apache + MySQL --> 192.168.1.20
   Apache is configured to listen on port 8080

**Varnish configuration**

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 4.0

backend default {
    .host = "192.168.1.20";
    .port = "8080";
}

acl purge {
    "192.168.1.20";
}






sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern header required"));
        }
        ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }




    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart and checkout requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # static files are always cacheable. remove SSL flag and cookie
        if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/.*\.(ico|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|tiff|bmp|mp3|ogg|svg|swf|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$") {
        unset req.http.Https;
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    return (hash);
}






sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

}






sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    # images, css and js are cacheable by default so we have to remove cookie also
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        if (bereq.url !~ "\.(ico|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|tiff|bmp|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|svg|swf|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)(\?|$)") {
            set beresp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
            set beresp.http.Expires = "-1";
            set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
            set beresp.grace = 1m;
        }
    }
    return (deliver);
}






sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

}
```

**Nginx configuration**

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl; 

        server_name magentotest.devcom;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/nginx.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
```

Comment: change 127.0.0.1 to something different

Comment: I changed to proxy_pass http://192.168.1.22:80; but nothing change, content is still not cached

Comment: I also tried the configuration reported on GitHub https://github.com/fballiano/docker-nginx-ssl-for-magento2/blob/master/nginx-default.conf I really don't understand why Varnish doesn't cache Nginx requests. If I disable NGINX SSL and visit the website on port 80 all requests on second visit are cached, but if I visit the website on SSL nothing is cached.

Answer (score 0):

Your Nginx Config is....

[image]

Using the nginx's test certificate is not cached in browser.

The cache works properly only if you use a formal certificate, such as let's encrypt.

After applying the official certificate to nginx, if you test your browser, you can see that it becomes a disk cache right away.
[image]